# video not stored to my folder when i use file->move() method

Tags: php, laravel, upload, crud

this the code in my controller

```
$files = $request->file('video');
$files_extension = 'mp4';
$file_name = time() . '.' . $files_extension ;
$path = '/uploads/courses/lectures/' ;
$files->move($path , $file_name) ;
$validated = $request->validate([
'title' => 'string|required' ,
'desc' => 'required' ,
'video' => 'nullable'
]);
$validated['video'] = $file_name ;
$validated['session_id'] = $id ;
$lecture = Lecture::create($validated) ;
$session = $lecture->session ;
return redirect(route('lecture.index' , $session));
```

in this code he just stored the name in database but not move the video to the folder lectures and i can't reached to it if he not stored

Any one can help me?

I tried in several ways, but for your information, when I use photos instead of videos, the photos go to my folder, but with videos, they do not work
I changed the sizing settings

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify  `public_path()` before your path. Try something like this

```
$path = public_path().'/uploads/courses/lectures/';
```

Increase limits in `php.ini` as well. Try changing these to high enough values:

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
memory_limit = 32M
```